# Convert relationed data to list

Tags: c#

I'm currently working in windows forms c# application with SQL managment studio and I  have two tables

```
+-------------------------------+
|           Category            |
+-------------------------------+
| CategoryId (UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) |
| Name (VARCHAR(255))           |
| CreatedBy(VARCHAR(255))       |
| CreationDate(DATETIME)        |
+-------------------------------+


+-----------------------------+
|           Product           |
+-----------------------------+
| ProductId(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) |
| CategoryId (FK)             |
| Name(VARCHAR(255))          |
| CreatedBy(VARCHAR(255))     |
| CreationDate(DATETIME)      |
| IsDeleted(BIT)              |
+-----------------------------+
```

In c# I get data from datatable as:

```
var data = db.GetTableBySQL("usp_RedMarks_Get");
```

I want to convert this datatable into a list to get list of products in each  categories, something like this:

```
  private List<Category> GetData()
        {
            // Simulate a database...
            Category c1 = new Category("Fruit", new List<string>() { "Banana", "Apple" });
            Category c2 = new Category("Vegetables", new List<string>() { "Avocado", "Tomato" });
            Category c3 = new Category("Programming Languages", new List<string>() { "C#", "Visual Basic" });
            Category c4 = new Category("Stars", new List<string>() { "Venus", "Mars" });

            List<Category> result = new List<Category>();
            result.Add(c1);
            result.Add(c2);
            result.Add(c3);
            result.Add(c4);

            return result;
        }
    }

class Category
    {
        public string Name;
        public List<string> Items;
        public Category(string name,List<string> items)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Items = items;
        }
    }
```

Stored Procedure:

```
SELECT C.Name AS 'categoryName', P.Name AS 'productName'
FROM Category AS C
INNER JOIN Product AS P ON C.CategoryId = P.CategoryId
ORDER BY C.Name
```

How can I achieve that? Regards

Comment: Take a look on Entity Framework. It is the library and framework you are looking for.

Comment: i don't know how advanced are you, but @ZorgoZ solution is good aproach if you're looking for ORM. Entity Framework or NHibernate could help. if you are beginner you should fill `Dataset` object with stored procedure results and then create a `Dictionary` object - not `List`, where `Key` is category and `Item` is your item.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use entity framework for whatever reason. You could use something more lightweight and easier to get started with library such as Dapper. Then you can map it quite easily like below:

```
var productWithCategories = 
       conn.Query<Product, Category>(@"
            SELECT p.*, c.*
            FROM Product p
            INNER JOIN Category c ON c.Id = p.CategoryId                    
            ", (product, category) => {
                 category.Products = category.Products ?? new List<Product>();
                 category.Products.Add(product); 
                 return category;
             }).AsQueryable();
```

With Entity Framework something like this:

```
public class Product
{
   ...
   public List<Category> Categories {get;set;}
}
public class Category
{
   ...
   public int ProductId {get;set;}
   public Product Product {get;set;}
}
public class MyDataContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
using (MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext())
{
    var categories = (from p in db.Products
                  join c in db.Categories
                  on p.CategoryId equals c.Id
                  select c).ToList();
     string productName = categories.First().Product.Name;

}
```

Comment: I just installed Entity Framework in my project. How should be solution using it?, I have datatable , now how can I do a List with Entity Framework with this datatable?

Comment: See my example above for EF it doesnt cover it all but in principle. Do you need a datatable? Maybe its more simple for you to get started with Dapper since you dont have to configure it...